# save list into text file with space avoid single quoets and conman in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, text

I want to write the output into the text files without single quotes and common just need a single space.
"Data"(in the program)  gives correct output but can't write into the text files.

```
#data clean 
save_path = "C:/Users/bubai/Desktop/try/preprosesing/output/"
path =      "C:/Users/bubai/Desktop/try/preprosesing/data/" 
all_txt_files = os.listdir(path)
for txt in all_txt_files:
    txt_dir = path + txt   #name +path
    with open(txt_dir, 'r',encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
            clean = txt_file.read()
           
    #removing unwanted character
           data = res.replace('\n', '')
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(res)
            data = []
            for x in tokens:
                if x not in stopword:
                    data.append(x)
            print("removed stopword")
    data = print(*data, sep =' ')  
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, txt)
    output_file = open(completeName,"w",encoding = "utf-8")   #for write
    output_file.write(str(data))
txt_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

my output

> इंदिरा गोस्वामी परिचय मूल नाम मामोनी रायसम गोस्वामीजन्म नवंबर गुवाहाटी असमभाषा असमिया अंग्रेजीविधाएँ कहानी उपन्यास शोध आत्मकथामुख्य कृतियाँ उपन्यास चेनाबार नीलकंठी ब्रज अहिरन छिन्नमस्ता मामरे धारा तरोवाल दाताल हातीर उवे खोवा हावदा तेज अरु धूलि धूसरित पृष्ठ ब्लडस्टेंड पेजिज दक्षिणी कामरूप गाथा कहानी संग्रह चिनाकी मरम कइना हृदय एक नदीर नाम प्रिय गल्पो आत्मकथा आधा लेखा दस्तावेज शोध रामायण फ्रॉम गंगा टू ब्रह्मपुत्र सम्मान पुरस्कार प्रिंसिपल प्रिंस क्लाउस लाउरेट पुरस्कार डच सरकार अंतरराष्ट्रीय तुलसी पुरस्कार फ्लोरिडा अंतरराष्ट्रीय विश्वविद्यालय साहित्य अकादमी पुरस्कार असम साहित्य सभा पुरस्कार भारत निर्माण पुरस्कार सौहार्द पुरस्कार उत्तर प्रदेश हिंदी संस्थान कमलकुमारी फाउंडेशन पुरस्कार निधन नवंबर गुवाहाटी असम

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
# Don't forget to import os, nltk
save_path = "C:/Users/bubai/Desktop/try/preprosesing/output/"
path =      "C:/Users/bubai/Desktop/try/preprosesing/data/" 
all_txt_files = os.listdir(path)
for txt in all_txt_files:
    txt_dir = path + txt   #name +path
    with open(txt_dir, 'r',encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
            clean = txt_file.read()
           
    #removing unwanted character
           data = res.replace('\n', '')
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(res)
            data = []
            for x in tokens:
                if x not in stopword:
                    data.append(x)
            print("removed stopword")

    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, txt)
    with open(completeName, "w") as f:
        f.write(" ".join(data))
```

Comment: error   f.write(data)

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Comment: Can you give me the value of data at the point I have commented on updated post.

Comment: /*इंदिरा गोस्वामी परिचय मूल नाम मामोनी रायसम गोस्वामीजन्म नवंबर गुवाहाटी असमभाषा असमिया अंग्रेजीविधाएँ कहानी उपन्यास शोध आत्मकथामुख्य कृतियाँ उपन्यास चेनाबार नीलकंठी ब्रज अहिरन छिन्नमस्ता मामरे धारा तरोवाल दाताल हातीर उवे खोवा हावदा तेज अरु धूलि धूसरित पृष्ठ ब्लडस्टेंड पेजिज दक्षिणी कामरूप गाथा कहानी वाहाटी असम */

Comment: this is the output

Comment: Can we directly write the string to the file?

Comment: @AstikGabani yes

Comment: but if i do that then single quotes and common are there in the output text file

Comment: is the type of data list?

Comment: Got it every thing. @riya it seems to be a final updated post. Please verify it

Comment: Welcome @riya  That's my pleasure

Comment: can u tell me how to add new line after one word @AstikGabani

Comment: Try to use: "\n".join(data)    here data is the list of all the words.